# Authentication problem with multi-tier app in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-web-app-service

I have `two apps` deployed on `two separate Azure web services` for containers. One for frontend is a `VUE js app` running on nginx the other is `Python FastAPI API` running on uvicorn. I want users to authenticate with Azure Active Directory.

When users enter frontend endpoint I want them to authenticate with AAD. When they will be authenticated I want them to be able to see data from backend. I also want them to authenticate with backend directly. From what I understand I want to authenticate with backend via frontend.
I followed instructions from MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux where I configured Azure `Authentication/Authorization` for both front and backend and delegated permissions from frontend.

Authentication with backend works correctly but when I try to access frontend authentication flow is triggered and I'm being redirected to `https://My-frontend-app/.auth/login/aad/callback` and get error `500`.

In frontend app registration authorisation I have configured "`web`" and entered this url `https://My-frontend-app/.auth/login/aad/callback`

Thanks for your help in advance. This is my first post so maybe I didn't give enough information.

Comment: Please share the request or correlation id and timestamp for the failed authentication request.

Comment: Timestamp: 2020-08-19T14:42:46.785803631Z
Connection id "0HM23903KU8JQ", 
Request id "0HM23903KU8JQ:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. Is this sufficient ?

Comment: Correlation Id should be a GUID, yours may be coming from the App Service Auth layer and not AAD. Can you share the full error detail or screen?

Comment: Finally I managed to solve this issue. I didn't configure CORS and didn't attach access token into request headers. Thanks for help. Unfortunately I don't have access to AAD and coudn't get correlation id.